# SQL Server 2008 synchronization at 00:00 every day

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have desktop application and I want that all new data in this application that are stored in local DB will synchronize every day at 00:00 to production database.

I was looking at the MS Sync Framework

http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2008/01/05/Microsoft-Sync-Framework-Support-in-Visual-Studio-2008.aspx

is this solution correct or how is the best way to synchronize two databases at 00:00 every day.

Application is written in C# and using local SQL Server 2008

Comment: The Sync Framework looks like a great solution to me. Do you have any concern?

Comment: The time of day is distacting from the real issue - you're just asking how to sync two databases essentially.

Comment: Widor exactly. How to sync two databases.

Comment: SoMoS I am just thinking if this is the right approach with MS Sync Framework.

Comment: In addition to other comments, can I suggest that you run your sync (or any other scheduled process) at either 23h55 or 00h05, but never 00h00. It just causes confusion (in code, discussions, documentation etc.) about what day it is when the process starts, as well as potentially leading to bugs in any related date/time calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use database [replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198) and specify a [synchronization schedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151702.aspx).

Comment: is synchronization schedule better than using sync framework? can i sync at specific time?

Comment: A synchronization schedule is implemented by a SQLServer Agent job and can be scheduled as usual.

Comment: hmm I am searching for some example to see how it works and how to implement it in sql management studio but there is no example. Do you have one maybe?

Comment: Here maybe? http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-replication-crib-sheet/

Comment: Thanks, but this is replication. For replication I need VPN which is not good for my example. I also need Publisher and Subscriber.